# Lexical editor: Cleanup HTML that gets generated using $generateHTMLfromNodes

Tags: lexicaljs

I am generating HTML from Lexical using $`generateHTMLfromNodes`.

The HTML code I get is e.g. this one:

```
<p dir="ltr">
<span>Hello </span>
<s>
<i>
<em class="editor-text-strikethrough">crazy frog</em>
</i>
</s>
</p>
```

How can I get rid of:

- dir="ltr"
- class="editor-text-strikethrough

Also, why is there a span automagically inserted inside each `<p></p>`-tag?
And why is there an `<i>` and an `<em>` when one would be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and described it here: https://github.com/facebook/lexical/discussions/3828#discussioncomment-5804228